# Create a global temporary table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, temp-tables

I am new to SQL. I want to create a (global or not) temporary table in Oracle SQL which will include a simple selection of data of the form `SELECT * FROM tbl_NAME WHERE...` and which after the end of my session will be deleted (just like the MSFT SQL temporary tables of the form `##tbl_NAME`).

I found online that one way to do it is:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table
SELECT * FROM tbl_NAME WHERE conditions.
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

although I get the error **ORA-00904: invalid identifier**

I also found that another alternative is

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table AS 
SELECT * FROM tbl_NAME WHERE conditions;
```

which gives the error **ORA-00905: missing keyword**.

Please note that I already know that one alternative that works is:

```
DROP TABLE    tmp_table;
CREATE TABLE    tmp_table AS 
SELECT      * FROM tbl_NAME; 
DROP TABLE    tmp_table;
```

Comment: Just FYI: Tom Kyte always [warns](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5824706700346810645) about MS SQL people using temporary tables in Oracle instead of subselects.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do with *rows* comes first; `SELECT` comes next:

```
SQL> create global temporary table gtt_dept
  2  on commit preserve rows                       --> first
  3  as
  4  select * from dept;                         --> next

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: The example you showed me indeed created the table although after the end of my session it was not removed which is the main reason that I need to use a temp. table.

Comment: @Whitebeard13 Did you use `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` or `on commit delete rows`?

Comment: Preserve . I made a mistake and I wrote delete in my question initially and that's why the answer of Littlefoot has delete

Comment: Exactly. I just fixed the syntax.

Comment: Saying "after the end of my session it was not removed" - what is "it"? The table itself? You have to drop it, it won't just *disappear* (but its contents will).

Comment: Hi Littlefoot. Thanks for making it clear. As I said I am looking for a table which will be deleted/removed/dropped after the end of session. As I mentioned I am looking something similar to the temporary tables of msft sql with the ## in front of the table name.

Comment: @Whitebeard13 there is no such thing in Oracle, and even if there was, identifiers can contain `#` but must start with a letter. Also, schema objects appearing and disappearing at runtime would play havoc with dependency tracking and the PL/SL compiler, so it wouldn't be that useful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## The below format you had shown works in TERADATA

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table
SELECT * FROM tbl_NAME WHERE conditions.
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

## In Oracle it works like this

create global temporary table gtt_dept
on commit preserve rows
as
select * from dept;